# AngularJS - States from submodule not recognized by main module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, boilerplate

I am currently geting an error trying to use states defined on my submodule. I am working on this [AngularJS-Boilerplate](https://github.com/jbutko/AngularJS-Boilerplate) and they code in a way that i am not very used to.

This is my main module:

```
;(function() {


  /**
   * Definition of the main app module and its dependencies
   */
  angular
    .module('boilerplate', [
      'ui.router',
      'boilerplate.demo'
    ])
    .config(config);


  config.$inject = ['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', '$authProvider'];

  function config($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider, $authProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    $authProvider.facebook({
      clientId: '471453806577471',
      responseType: 'token'
    });

  }

  /**
   * Run block
   */
  angular
    .module('boilerplate')
    .run(run);

  run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams','$location'];

  function run($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location) {
    $state.go('boilerplate.home');

  }


})();
```

This is my submodule:

```
;(function() {


  /**
   * Definition of the main app module and its dependencies
   */
  angular
    .module('boilerplate.demo', [
      'ui.router',
    ])
    .config(config);

  // safe dependency injection
  // this prevents minification issues
  config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function config($stateProvider) {
    console.log('states');
    $stateProvider
            .state('boilerplate.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'app/demo/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'MainController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

  }

})();
```

I get this error:

> angular.js:11706 Error: Could not resolve 'boilerplate.home' from state ''

If I put $stateProvider in the main module and change the controllers module also to the main module it works. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a state provider in the main module as well, at least a default one. Try putting something like this in your main module:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('boilerplate', {
            url: '',
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl: 'app/demo/partials/blank.html' //some empty template, it will be overridden
        })
```

Please note that when creating states in separate modules, hierarchy in state naming must be satisfied. If your abstract or default state is named **boilerplate**, your submodule state must be named **boilerplate.something**.

Edit:

I forgot to add one thing. In your submodule's $stateProvider state definition, you need to add **parent** property. It should look something like this:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('boilerplate.home', {
                url: '/home',
                parent: 'boilerplate',
                templateUrl: 'app/demo/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'MainController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
```

Basically, child (submodule's) state should be aware on it's parent state.

Comment: Thanks! Now it recognizes the state, but it does not load the partial :( 
And it is recognizing the partial, cause it raises an error if i put an invalid partial path.